# Which is the regular expression for the text that starts with symbol - and ends with the symbol "?

Tags: regex, expression, sublimetext2

I try to find a regular expression but it's impossible. I have a json file and i want to replace some text with sublimeText2.
I want to replace what starts with the symbol - and ends with the symbol " but i don't want to replace the " symbol.
for example: I have the following text: hello - good morning"
I want to keep the text: hello"
Which is the regular expression for the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely what you are looking for:

```
-.*(?=")
```

According to the sublime text 2 documentation, it uses the perl regex engine from [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html#boost_regex.syntax.perl_syntax.lookahead), which says it supports lookahead.  So this should work for you.